# Formatting panel contents in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a `panel`, in which I want the content to displayed vertically. To do that, I'm using this line of code:

```
rightPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

As I'm using `textfields`, then I would like them to take up one line. But by using the line of code specified above, `textfields` inside the panel get maximized and when I change the window size, the size of the `textfield` changes accordingly. I also tried removing it, but then the contents inside the panel get displayed horizontally and won't fit inside the panel.

Here is the image of the result:

[image]

And here is the code where the content of the panel gets created:

```
//Creates the form for data and button to save it.
            final TextField name;
            final TextField eMail;
            final TextField dateOfBirth;
            final TextField address;
            JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
            name = new TextField ();
            JLabel eMailLabel = new JLabel("E-mail:");
            eMail = new TextField ();
            JLabel dateOfBirthLabel = new JLabel("Date of birth:");
            dateOfBirth = new TextField ();
            JLabel addressLabel = new JLabel("Address:");
            address = new TextField ();
            rightPanel.add(nameLabel);
            rightPanel.add(name);
            rightPanel.add(eMailLabel);
            rightPanel.add(eMail);
            rightPanel.add(dateOfBirthLabel);
            rightPanel.add(dateOfBirth);
            rightPanel.add(addressLabel);
            rightPanel.add(address);
            rightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20, 20)));
            JButton save = new JButton("Save");
            rightPanel.add(save);
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question? How would you like it to work? What is the problem?

Comment: @Simon André Forsberg Basically I want the textfields to take up one row, not fill up the entire panel. You can see the problem in the picture here: http://i.imgur.com/OuMMhN6.png

Comment: We can't comment and make suggestions on your code without seeing it. And we won't implement everything for you.

Comment: Please add some more code to your question. You might have an error in the code elsewhere than the line above.

Comment: I edited the post and added the image with the code that creates the panels contents, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill the rest of the panel with something, use swing.Box

```
import javax.swing.Box;
rightPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
```

put the box in the position where you want the space to apear

More on that subject http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler

You also need to limit maximum height of the input boxes (for each input call - create method probably):

```
input.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, input.getMinimumSize().height));
```

Comment: I would like the box to appear below the save button, although adding the line of code there doesn't change anything.

Comment: Now it creates a small space, but still doesn't solve the problem as I would like it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your panel in the NORTH part of a BorderLayout -- in the EAST or CENTER parts of a BorderLayout, the panel stretches up/down, but not in the North.  And, of course, you can put it in its own JPanel with that BorderLayout, and then put THAT JPanel in another layout however you want.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.TextField;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class RightPanel extends JFrame
{
    TextField name;
    TextField eMail;
    TextField dateOfBirth;
    TextField address;

    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        RightPanel rp = new RightPanel();
        rp.createUI();
        rp.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createUI()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    //Creates the form for data and button to save it.
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
    name = new TextField ();

    JLabel eMailLabel = new JLabel("E-mail:");
    eMail = new TextField ();

    JLabel dateOfBirthLabel = new JLabel("Date of birth:");
    dateOfBirth = new TextField ();

    JLabel addressLabel = new JLabel("Address:");
    address = new TextField ();

    rightPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    rightPanel.add(nameLabel);
    rightPanel.add(name);
    rightPanel.add(eMailLabel);
    rightPanel.add(eMail);
    rightPanel.add(dateOfBirthLabel);
    rightPanel.add(dateOfBirth);
    rightPanel.add(addressLabel);
    rightPanel.add(address);
    rightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20, 20)));
    JButton save = new JButton("Save");
    rightPanel.add(save);

    JPanel doNotStretchPanel = new JPanel();
    doNotStretchPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    doNotStretchPanel.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    this.add(doNotStretchPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    pack();
  }

}
```